# Preroll ad not playing on KMC

Tags: kaltura, preroll

I am using the kaltura player to play preroll ads. I tried the sample ad on KMC http://player.kaltura.com/docs/kvast. Here's my code:

```
kWidget.embed({
        targetId: "kaltura_player_1446547025",
        wid: "_2027961",
        uiconf_id: "32020091",
        cache_st: "1446547025",
        entry_id: "1_3gmgqn2e",
        flashvars: {
            "vast": {
                "prerollUrl" : "https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x360&iu=/6062/iab_vast_samples/skippable&ciu_szs=300x250,728x90&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&correlator=[timestamp]",
                "numPreroll" : "1",
                "preSequence" : "1",
                "htmlCompanions" : "testCompanion:300:250;testLongCompanion:728:90;",
                "timeout" : "4",
                "storeSession" : false,
                "skipOffset" : "5",
                "unescapeAdUrls" : false
            },
            "skipBtn": {
                "skipOffset" : "5",
                "label" : "Skip Ad"
            },
            "noticeMessage": {
                "text" : "Advertisment {sequenceProxy.timeRemaining|timeFormat}"
            },
            "adsOnReplay" : true
        }
    })
```

Comment: How did you set the preroll ad ? Please provide some more info regarding your configuration

Comment: @vadimtar: I have amended my question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

i've added your data into the following example - I can see the ad
`Same code from the question`
http://jsfiddle.net/itayKinnrot/gtpjh3pf/

Answer (score 0):

As @Itay Kinnrot said, everything works fine.The problem is with the preroll video - it doesn't play:

https://redirector.gvt1.com/videoplayback/id/8bd2c53a3e15469d/itag/18/source/gfp_video_ads/requiressl/yes/ip/0.0.0.0/ipbits/0/expire/1447869905/sparams/ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl/signature/700D521CA3B3D0F7AAAEB146503557132ABD1192.4A9A6774B42C29531E37E4F98905AEAB415110C4/key/ck2/file/file.mp4

if you open Itay's example in Firefox, you will see the pre roll plays just fine (because another video is loaded at Firefox)